# SQL How to find specific value that is not in another result

Tags: mysql, sql

tldr;
I want to filter out result by checking if current result **DOES NOT EXIST** in another result

So currently I have these 2 queries

```
SELECT
  dosen.nama
FROM
  dosen AS dosen 
  INNER JOIN role as role
    ON dosen.NIP = role.NIP
WHERE
    role.Role != 'dosen'
    AND
    dosen.Nama LIKE '%em%'
```

Resulting in

```
| nama |
| RATIH KEMALA DEWI, SP. M.Si | 
| GEMA PARASTI MINDARA, S.Si., M.Kom |
```

and

```
SELECT 
  dosen.nama 
FROM 
  dosen AS dosen 
INNER JOIN 
  chats as chats ON dosen.NIP = chats.KonselorNIP 
WHERE 
  chats.ThreadStatus = 'OPEN'
```

Resulting in (which it currently only has one data)

```
| nama |
| GEMA PARASTI MINDARA, S.Si., M.Kom |
```

As far as my logic goes, this is what I came up with

```
SELECT
    dosen.nama
FROM
  dosen AS dosen 
  INNER JOIN role as role
    ON dosen.NIP = role.NIP
WHERE
    role.Role != 'dosen'
    AND
    dosen.Nama LIKE '%em%'
    AND NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT dosen.nama FROM dosen AS dosen INNER JOIN chats as chats ON dosen.NIP = chats.KonselorNIP WHERE chats.ThreadStatus = 'OPEN')
```

But the result is empty, what I expected was

```
| nama |
| RATIH KEMALA DEWI, SP. M.Si |
```

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Please explain what you want the overall query to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using not in and sorting out where clauses gives the exact wanted result

So first the query foes looking for names `not in` 3rd table (chats)
then look in filtered result for name fits `like`, and last look for the role.

Sorry if my understanding of mysql is still messy, but this works

```
SELECT 
  d.nama
FROM 
  dosen d
JOIN
  role r on r.NIP = d.NIP
WHERE 
  d.Nama NOT IN (SELECT d2.nama FROM dosen d2 JOIN chats c ON c.KonselorNIP = d2.NIP)
  AND
  d.Nama LIKE '%em%'
  AND
  r.Role != 'dosen'
```